# Detecting login credentials abuse

Tags: web, authentication, credentials, detection

I am the webmaster for a small, growing industrial association. Soon, I will have to implement a restricted, members-only section for the website.

The problem is that our organization membership both includes big companies as well as amateur “clubs” (it's a relatively new industry…).

It is clear that those clubs will share the login ID they will use to log onto our website. The problem is to detect whether one of their members will share the login credentials with people who would not normally supposed to be accessing the website (there is no objection for such a club to have all it’s members get on the website).

I have thought about logging along with each sign-on the IP address as well as the OS and the browser used; if the OS/Browser stays constant and there are no more than, say, 10 different IP addresses, the account is clearly used by very few different computers.

But if there are 50 OS/Browser combination and 150 different IPs, the credentials have obviously been disseminated far, and there would be then cause for action, such as modifying the password.

Of course, it is extremely annoying when your password is being unilaterally changed. So, for this problem, I thought about allowing the “clubs” to manage their own list of sub-accounts, and therefore if abuse is suspected, the user responsible would be easily pinned-down, and this “sub-member” alone would face the annoyance of a password change.

**Question:
What potential problems would anyone see with such an approach?**

Comment: I bet you'll get better responses from serverfault.com.  This is a programming site.

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason why you can't force each club member to register (just straight-up, not necessarily as a sub or a similar complex structure)?  Perhaps give each club some sort of code to use just when the users register so you can automatically create their accounts and affiliate them with a club, but you then have direct accounting of each member without an onerous process that the club has to manage themselves.  Then it's much easier to determine if a given account is being spread around (disparate IP accesses in given periods of time).

Clearly then you can also set a limit on the number of affiliated accounts per club, should you want to do so.  This is basically what you've suggested, I suppose, but I would try to keep any onerous management tasks out of the hands of your users if at all possible.  If you can manage club-affiliated signups, you should, rather than forcing someone at the club to manage them for you.

Also, while some sort of heuristic based on IP and credentials is probably fine, I would stay away from incorporating user-agent, or at least caring too much about it.  Seeing a few different UAs from the same IP - depending on your expected userbase, I suppose - isn't really that unusual.  I use several browsers in the course of my day due to website bugs, etc. and unless someone is using a machine as a proxy, it's not evidence of anything nefarious.

Comment: Oops, we think alike...  I'll leave my response a few minutes to have the OP see that several people suggest the registration.  But I'll then delete my response, no point in doubling up!